# My WordPress site auto-redirects to another site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, http-equiv

I have one site that is auto-redirecting to another site that I don't know.

[dreamangelfashion.com](http://dreamangelfashion.com/) is my site, when I open it will redirect to [http://queakshopgreet.com](http://queakshopgreet.com/?a=400642&c=rom). I have looked at header and index files and I didn't find anything. When I check view-source of page it will display

```html
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;http://queakshopgreet.com/?a=400642&c=rom">
```

and I can also open my-account of my site.

How can I fix this?

Comment: hacked perhaps? just remove that line of code

Comment: I have checked all the possibilities and files but i didn't find from where it is getting redirected.

Comment: if you can see that in source then it has to be in your code somewhere

Comment: i tried to find but i can't , so please tell me where and which file i have to find for this .because this redirect only home page i can open my-account page...!

Comment: oh yup your in trouble "Trojan: JS/Redirector.NY " detected. i would take that site down and clean it

Comment: Check your functions file, or actually it could be in any file that can be used to hook into the `get_header` function. It seems it's been hacked, so take it down, and clean it out. Start from fresh. Or at the very least, search ALL of your website files for that domain, and it might find the script.